# I getting an error variable driver of type Object in Comparator.comparingDouble( ) method

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I wanted to Match the rider with the nearest available drivers. For that I am using Comparator.comparingDouble() method.

```
 private List<Driver> findNearbyDrivers(Rider rider) {
        List<Driver> availableDriverList = getAvailableDriverList();
        List<Driver> nearbyDrivers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Driver driver : availableDriverList) {
            if (calculateDistance(rider.getLocation(), driver.getLocation()) <= MAX_DISTANCE_IN_KM) {
                nearbyDrivers.add(driver);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(nearbyDrivers,
                Comparator.comparingDouble(driver -> calculateDistance(rider.getLocation(),driver.getLocation()))
                        .thenComparing(driver -> ((Driver) driver).getDriver_id())
        );

        return nearbyDrivers;
```

When I am trying to sort using collection.sort( ) I could not able to use **driver.getLocation()** in lamda expression of comparator in calculateDistance() . **It is treating driver as  of type Object and not as Driver.**

For the code to work I have to typecast explicitly. I could not able to understand the reason that why it is treating driver as Object type

Distance logic is separated in another method **calculateDistance();**

```
public double calculateDistance(Location rider,Location driver){
       
    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(driver.getxPosition() - rider.getxPosition(), 2) + Math.pow(driver.getyPosition() - rider.getyPosition(), 2));
    return distance; 

}
```

I have Ensured  nearBydriverList is explicitly declared as List<Driver>. I am confused why it is considering driver as a object type.

I am expecting it to work without explicit typecasting

**I am getting below error-`**

```
 Comparator.comparingDouble(driver -> calculateDistance(rider.getLocation(),driver.getLocation()))
                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getLocation()
  location: variable driver of type Object
```

Comment: You have to cast comparator to (ToDoubleFunction<Driver>)

`Collections.sort(nearbyDrivers, Comparator.comparingDouble((ToDoubleFunction<Driver>) driver -> calculateDistance(rider.getLocation(), driver.getLocation())).thenComparing(driver -> ((Driver) driver).getDriver_id()));`

Answer (score 0):

In `Comparator.comparingDouble(driver ->` nothing tells it that the variable **named** `driver` is of `Driver` kind.

By default, it's an `Object`.

Don't be tricked (but I think you aren't) by the `for (Driver driver` that you have above: `driver` has the kind `Driver`, yes, but for the time of the `for` loop only.
And then the `driver` you're using in the `Comparator.comparingDouble` is a new local variable, created with the default type, because no other one is provided, `Object`.

In your comparator, changing to `Comparator.comparingDouble((Driver) driver ->` or something like that, should succeed.

Or `Comparator<Driver>.comparingDouble(driver ->`, maybe.

I do agree that I would have expected that from: `nearbyDrivers` of kind `List<Driver>`, `driver` in `Comparator.comparingDouble` would have immediately the good type `Driver` too...
But if your compiler refuses, it's not as implicit as I would have thought.

But I think it translates it to `Comparator<Object>.comparingDouble` as `Comparator<T>` is generic, but you're using it raw.

Comment: But in the the method- driver -> calculateDistance(rider.getLocation(),driver.getLocation()),rider.getLocation( ) is working fine without any explicit casting. I am only getting an error for driver.getLocation()

Comment: Because rider is given for `Rider` (which has a `getLocation()` also, then) from the method parameter. But `Comparator<T>.comparingDouble(T a ->` create an `a` local variable of type T. A `Comparator<String>.comparingDouble(a ->` a `a` of type String, A `Comparator<Double>.comparingDouble(a ->` `a` is a Double, and in `Comparator.comparingDouble(a ->` `a` or `Comparator<?>.comparingDouble(a ->` `a` or `Comparator<Object>.comparingDouble(a ->` `a` is an Object. You need to do a `Comparator<Driver>.comparingDouble(a ->` to have for `a`, a Driver.